# C# - If I use backgroundWorker nothing is displayed in the treeView control

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, treeview, backgroundworker

I like to populate array "numbers" in a "treeView1" control.
All works well if I don't use backgroundWorker control.

If I use backgroundWorker nothing is displayed in the treeView1. It looks like the code is stuck in the foreach loop.

[image]

```
        //Step1
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    //Step2
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork_1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[5];
        numbers[0] = 1;
        numbers[1] = 2;
        numbers[2] = 3;
        numbers[3] = 4;
        numbers[4] = 5;

        foreach (int element in numbers)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(element.ToString());
        }
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

I tried all you suggested below and still doesn't display anything

```
        //Step1
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    //Step2
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork_1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

        int[] numbers = new int[5];
        numbers[0] = 1;
        numbers[1] = 2;
        numbers[2] = 3;
        numbers[3] = 4;
        numbers[4] = 5;
        treeView1.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (int element in numbers)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(element.ToString());
        }
        treeView1.EndUpdate();
        button1.Enabled = true;
        treeView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Thanks to Banjamin now all work :)

```
        //Step1
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    //Step2
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork_1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

        int[] numbers = new int[5];
        numbers[0] = 1;
        numbers[1] = 2;
        numbers[2] = 3;
        numbers[3] = 4;
        numbers[4] = 5;

        treeView1.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            foreach (int element in numbers)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(element.ToString());
            }
        });

        treeView1.EndUpdate();
        //button1.Enabled = true;
        treeView1.Refresh();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Completed");
        button1.Invoke((Action)delegate { button1.Enabled = true; });
    }
```

Comment: Is that DoWork handler actually hooked up to the background worker? Always useful to see the whole code file when resolving these types of issues.

Comment: Probably you have to refresh control after populate

Comment: You can't do this from a background thread.  Setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `false` is hiding the exceptions that are probably being thrown.  There's no reason to use a `BackgroundWorker` here, as you're not actually doing any work.

Comment: Have you tried calling treeView1.BeginUpdate() and treeView1.EndUpdate()? before and after you are making change to force repainting.

Comment: Messing with CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls only ever solves *one* problem, it adds fifty new ones that are a hundred times harder to debug.  You must write valid code, this is not it.

Comment: You should load your data in a background thread and then Invoke the main thread to build the UI tree nodes.

Comment: Actually if I change CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false the code is executed to the end and all work now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your code in the debugger you will get an exception popup giving you more details on what is going wrong:

> Additional information: Action being performed on this control is being called from the wrong thread. Marshal to the correct thread using Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke to perform this action.

You should always update your UI from the main (or window) thread of your application. The correct code is:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[5];
    numbers[0] = 1;
    numbers[1] = 2;
    numbers[2] = 3;
    numbers[3] = 4;
    numbers[4] = 5;

    treeView1.Invoke((Action)delegate 
    {
       foreach (int element in numbers)
       {
           treeView1.Nodes.Add(element.ToString());
       }
   });

   button1.Invoke((Action) delegate { button1.Enabled = true; });
}
```

By using the Invoke method on treeView1 and button1 you ensure the correct thread is used to update the UI.

Comment: All work if I don't use backgroundworker. 
Backgroundworker works well if I use List but never work if I use TreeView. 
The code stack inside the foreach loop and nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you. It works if I use Invoke (the last code you published)

Thank you

I am going to understand all this.

Comment: The only problem now is that the code never reach the end. I added MessageBox but it never appear. The threeView is displaying the array but the code never go out of the loop foreach!

Comment: You cannot do any UI related work inside the DoWork method. Showing a MessageBox should also be marshalled to the UI Thread. Try using `Invoke`.